# what's difference between make and initialize struct in golang?

Tags: go

We can make channel by `make` function, new an object by `{}` expression.

```
ch := make(chan interface{})
o := struct{}{}
```

But, what's difference between `make` and `{}` to new a map?

```
m0 := make(map[int]int)
m1 := map[int]int{}
```

Comment: there is no difference

Answer (score 13):

`make` can be used to initialize a map with preallocated space. It takes an optional second parameter.

`m0 := make(map[int]int, 1000) // allocateds space for 1000 entries`

Allocation takes cpu time. If you know how many entries there will be in the map you can preallocate space to all of them. This reduces execution time. Here is a program you can run to verify this.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "testing"

func BenchmarkWithMake(b *testing.B) {
    m0 := make(map[int]int, b.N)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        m0[i] = 1000
    }
}

func BenchmarkWithLitteral(b *testing.B) {
    m1 := map[int]int{}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        m1[i] = 1000
    }
}

func main() {
    bwm := testing.Benchmark(BenchmarkWithMake)
    fmt.Println(bwm) // gives 176 ns/op

    bwl := testing.Benchmark(BenchmarkWithLitteral)
    fmt.Println(bwl) // gives 259 ns/op
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for the `make` keyword:

> Map: An initial allocation is made according to the size but the
>   resulting map has length 0. The size may be omitted, in which case a
>   small starting size is allocated.

So, in the case of maps, there is no difference between using `make` and using an empty map literal.